# AutoMapper MaxDepth() method

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

In my project I have a one to many relationship from `Client -> Projects`. As such, in one of my views, I am trying to show all of the Projects that belong to that Client. So I have an `IEnumerable<ProjectDetailsViewModel>` that represents all of the clients projects.

The problem is that the `ProjectDetailsViewModel` has a `ClientDetailsViewModel` which then has an `IEnumerable<ProjectDetailsViewModel>` and so on and so forth creating an endless loop of identical entities.

Is this where it is appropriate to use the MaxDepth() method on that .ForMember()? If so, how do I use it in this case, and if not, what is the solution?

I have tried MaxDepth(1) on the `Client` and whilst this prevents the StackOverflow exception, it then doesn't hold any data in the view model for that client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I explicitly called AutoMapper from with the `AutoMapConfig` as such:

```
.ForMember(x => x.Client, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ClientDetailsViewModel>(src.Client)))
```

If I just define it as:

```
.ForMember(x => x.Client, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Client))
```

AutoMapper will know to stop after 1 recursion, and as I already have a map from `Client -> ClientDetailsViewModel` there is no problem.